# Localization of ASP.NET website is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, globalization

I am trying to localize an asp.net website, however its not working properly.

At the moment I have a user control, which I wish to localize.  So inside the UserControls folder, I have created an `App_LocalResources` folder, and 4 files which will be used for the localization :

1. UCMain.aspx.resx
2. UCMain.aspx.it-IT.resx
3. UCMain.aspx.de-DE.resx
4. UCMain.aspx.fr-FR.resx

In the UserControls folder, I have the main `UCMain.aspx` and inside the UCMain.aspx, I have the following simple file:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UCMain.ascx.cs" Inherits="SCPerformance.UserControls.UCMain" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="SCPerformance.Shared.Models" %>

<div class="PanelContainer">

    <div class="ContentTitle2">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAboutText" meta:resourcekey="lblAboutTextResource1" />
    </div>

</div>
```

Inside the localized files (resx) I have the following for all the languages:

```
Name                            Value
lblAboutTextResource1.Text      Informazione
```

The culture is set correctly when I click on the flags I have, so that is not the problem.  The problem is to retrieve the actual text, I am always getting the English version.

What could be my problem?

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: What's the output of `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`? If that's a matching culture in your application, have you definitely got a resource key named `lblAboutTextResource1` in that resource file?

Comment: hi matty, depends on the flag I click on, and yes I am getting a CurrentCulture, and yes I have a resource file for that with the correct language

Comment: The following works in code behind:-              lblAboutText.Text = (string) GetLocalResourceObject("lblAboutTextResource1.Text");

Comment: you're not setting the culture on `Page_Load` are you? If so, that's too late in the request life cycle as the control's text will have been retrieved before that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that works for my asp website with 4 languages ​​in my "GlobalRessource" folder.
Have you tried this option?

**C#** -- overload function InitializeCulture

```
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        try
        {
            string langID = "fr-FR";

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(langID);
            base.InitializeCulture();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

**ASP -->**  <%$ Resources:[resource directory name],[resource label name] %>

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAboutText" Text="<%$ Resources:UCMain,lblAboutTextResource1 %>" ></asp:Label>
```

Comment: doesn't that have to be in the GlobalResources though?